# How to obtain a generalized bayes estimator when we have random sample from the uniform distribution with a Pareto prior and a improper hyperprior?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, improper-prior

Let $\boldsymbol{X}=\left(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}\right)$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution on $(0, \theta),$ where $\theta>0$ is unknown. Let
$$
\pi(\theta)=b a^{b} \theta^{-(b+1)}, a<\theta<\infty
$$
be a prior density, where $b>1$ is known but $a>0$ is an unknown hyperparameter. Consider the estimation of $\theta$ under the squared error loss.
Let
$$
h(a)=\frac{1}{a}, \quad 0<a<\infty
$$
be an improper prior density for $a$. Obtain explicitly the generalized Bayes estimator.

---

Since if we have a finite risk, we can still solve the Bayes estimator with respect to $\pi(\theta)$.

My first attempt is to solve the posterior distribution and tried to work out the estimator using $$E(\Theta \mid x)=\int \theta \pi(\theta \mid x) d \theta.$$

The posterior distribution is

$$\pi(\theta|x)=\frac{\int_0^\infty f(x|\theta) \pi(\theta|a)h(a)da}{\int_a^\infty\int_0^\infty f(x|\theta)\pi(\theta|a)h(a) da d \theta}$$
but the problem is that numerator will goes to infinity.

After failed my first attempt, I tried to use the "kernel" approach by expressing $f(x|\theta)$ and $h(a)$ as a form of Pareto kernel.

My attempt is as follows:

Let $p\equiv\max\{X_1,X_2,....X_n\}$

Observe that

$$f(x^n|\theta)=\theta^{-n}\mathbf{1}(\theta>\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_n))\propto \theta^{-[(\theta-1)+1]}(n-1)p^{n-1}\mathbf{1}(p<\theta)$$
$$h(a)=\frac{1}{a}=a^{-(0+1)}\mathbf{1}(0<a)$$

So I try to obtain:
$$f(x|\theta) \pi(\theta|a)h(a)da \propto \theta^{-(n+b+1)}\mathbf{1}(\max(p,a)<\theta)a^{-(-b+1)}\mathbf{1}(0<a)$$ but I got completely stucked. I tried to find the expectation of $\theta\pi(\theta|x)$ by considering the whole thing as a pareto distribution but I don't know how to proceed from here.